# CodeIgniter Google Maps V3 API Library have to reload every time get a new direction without loading the page

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps-api-3, directions, codeigniter-library

I'm using [CodeIgniter Google Maps V3 API Library](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library/) and need to load the map each time I do a new direction, i can't refresh the page so i need to refresh just the map. how can done that ?

what i have to add in this code ?

```
    $config['center'] = 'auto';
    $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
    $config['directions'] = TRUE;
    $config['directionsStart'] = $directionsStart;
    $config['directionsWaypointArray'] = $directionsWaypointArray;
    $config['directionsEnd'] = $directionsEnd;
    $config['directionsDivID'] = 'directionsDiv';
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

Comment: there is possibility 'google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");' can work, and if yes how can add it in library ?

Comment: have you tried using AJAX? or why not just use the legit Google Maps JavaScript API for your CodeIgniter application? In fact, JavaScript works well with PHP.